# How to separate highlighted objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript

On my website I have 5 categories. In every category I have 1 image with a title and 1 description text. While hovering over the image the image and the text are highlighted in the same moment (by adding a class: "highligthCategory").

My problem is that every time I hover over any of 5 images, all 5 descriptions are highlighted. How could I limit the highlighting to the specific description related only to one image?

I assume the problem appears due to the fact that the second loop is inside the first loop, but because I have also event listeners I don't know how to separate them and make two loops work separately.

```
const category = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
const categoryText = document.querySelectorAll(".category-text");

const categoryArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(category);
const categoryTextArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(categoryText);


categoryArray.map(x => {

  x.addEventListener ("mouseover", function(e) {
    categoryTextArray.map(y =>
      y.classList.add("highligthCategory"));
    }, false);

  x.addEventListener ("mouseout", function(e) {
    categoryTextArray.map(y =>
      y.classList.remove("highligthCategory"));
    }, false);
});

HTML
<section id="service-1">
    <div class="row">
      <figure>
        <img class="category" src="img/1.svg" alt="" data-    type="feature">
      </figure>
      <h3>Service 1</h3>
      <p class="category-text">Example of the text.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML to illustrate what the relationship between `.category` and `.category-text` elements is ?

Comment: I've added the code of one of the sections above. There are 5 sections in total with the exactly same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the event listeners you're modifying all the `.category-text` elements instead of just those related to the element on which the event was triggered. You can do something like this to fix that:

```js
const categories = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
categories.forEach(category => {
  const description = category.closest('.row').querySelector('.category-text');
  category.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    description.classList.add("highligthCategory");
  }, false);

  category.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    description.classList.remove("highligthCategory");
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.highligthCategory {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="service-1">
  <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <img width="50" class="category" src="https://slm-assets0.secondlife.com/assets/696995/lightbox/a907d0cc6780bc3af5f83b8d1d54e1a3.jpg?1277109877" alt="" data- type="feature">
    </figure>
    <h3>Service 1</h3>
    <p class="category-text">Example of the text.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="service-1">
  <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <img  width="50" class="category" src="https://slm-assets0.secondlife.com/assets/696995/lightbox/a907d0cc6780bc3af5f83b8d1d54e1a3.jpg?1277109877" alt="" data- type="feature">
    </figure>
    <h3>Service 1</h3>
    <p class="category-text">Example of the text.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the above example, I'm creating a `description` variable which will hold a reference to the `.category-text` element related to the `.category` element in the current iteration and in the event listeners I'm modifying only this element's `classList`

Comment: Thank you - you are awesome - it perfectly solved my problem! 